# How to make element position change smooth using inline style tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an component that has an inline style tag and I pass in the array below it, one item at a time. This is to move a cursor from one place to another.

```
let myStyle =  [{
       left: "0",
       bottom: "-20px",
    },
    {
       left:"10px",
       bottom: "-30px",
    },
    {
       left: "20px",
       bottom: "-40px"
   }]



<div className="my-component" style={myStyle[i]}></div>
```

I use a slider to move through the array, but the slider does not always increase only by one. 
Dragging even lightly can make it jump two or three points and this screws up the movement.

Currently I think that `onChange`, if I slide too fast I get the start and end values only, and none in between. What I need is for my function to run on every step of the slider so that it moves incrementally one by one. The built-in `step` functionality does not seem to be a sufficient solution here.

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

I tried something like this hoping it would be true n-times and run at each `true`, even if the value were to be increased by multiple. Doesn't work

```
  handleChange(event) {
    if(currentStateValue - previousStateValue === 1){
    this.setState({
        value: event.target.value,
        });
        this.renderStuff() //run my function here
    }
   }
```

A for loop idea: if slider increases by 3 then I'd loop three. But it just runs the block so fast the cursor appears at the end position instantly.

```
       //OR
      let diff = currentState-previousState
      for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
      this.renderStuff() //run my function here
     }
```

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/a8vx0p41/5/) (that works better than my actual project), but is the same idea. I am open to totally new approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure a smoother transition with the adequate css property:

```
.my-component {
    transition: all 386ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the motion to remain stable and repeat regardless of the amount of change detected on the slider input.

Without modifying your current code too much, a solution might be to use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) to calculate the appropriate `objStyle` based on an arbitrary slider value like so:

```
// updated code in moveBox() class method    
if(diff === 1){

    const styleObjIndex = this.state.currentIndex % this.state.positions.length;

    this.setState({ styleObj:this.state.positions[styleObjIndex] })
}
```

[Here is an updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1oey37t/1/) - hope that helps!

Comment: It's a good idea! But it doesn't seem to help. It still behaves the same way. One idea I have is to replace the slider with a up/down counter. Click up or down to move, and the func will fire. If this fixes the issue then I know it's in the way the slider is communicating with the page. If not, them maybe it's a larger issue. But this would be for debugging only since I want a slider in the end.

Comment: Ah ok, I must have misunderstood the problem - just to be clear, you're wanting the slider to move the object directly from one `position[]` to the next? or are you wanting a smooth transition between the previous position and the next?

Comment: The second one. Your example fiddle works well, so I know it's difficult/impossible to tell what my problem might be since I cannot reproduce it. I thought maybe it was a problem in the pattern or something. This fiddle is what I meant https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/2c5d1Ly9/6/. It's the exact same thing as the slider only I can increment by one only to test. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: No problems :-)